# How to fixed the button at top after scrolling the window by using javascript?

Tags: javascript

i want my button to be fixed when i scroll the window please guide me, how can i do this?
this is my button:

```
<a href="" class="btn btn-primary HELPLINE NUMBER " id="NUMBER">HELPLINE NUMBER</a>
```

and this is my script

```
<script>

window.onscroll= function(){ myfunc(); }

var location_v=document.getElementById("NUMBER");
var pixtop=location_v.offsetTop;

function myfunc()
{
    if(window.pageYOffset > pixtop )
    {
        //alert("working");
        location_v.classList.add('stick');
    }
    else
    {
        location_v.classList.remove('stick');
    }

};


</script>
```

Comment: Fix it how?  How is it broken?

Comment: I think he wants a fixed-position button that stays on the page as a user scrolls, but it's clearly not. @Amy

Comment: You mean.. like what you'd get from "display: fixed" via css?

Comment: no, i need the button to be fix on the top when i scroll up direction,suppose we have a button on the web page with position absolute form top 100Px and from left 0Px so when we scroll up the window as well as the button to be start moving with each scroll events ,when the button to be reached at the top then there i need to fix button but using javascript and you can use css but to be added with javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `position: fixed` style attribute:

```
<a href="" class="btn btn-primary HELPLINE NUMBER " id="NUMBER" style="position: fixed;">HELPLINE NUMBER</a>
```

or set the style attribute via JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById ('NUMBER').style.position = 'fixed';
```

Comment: sir but i want to do this with the help of javascript or jquery to same 
 thing

Comment: Any reason for this? you could just change the style attribut via JavaScript, but that wouldnt change anything ```document.getElementById ('NUMBER').syle.position = 'fixed'; ```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need JavaScript for this, you can use an old `CSS` property: `position: fixed;`

Use the following in your css file

```
.btn {position: fixed;}
```

This applies to all elements which have a class named `btn`